Dropdown keeps appearing after clicking add job button, also auto update total not working
Error Image Screenshoot
Can anyone shed a light for this error
Everytime I click the "tambah pekerjaan" button, the previous value shows up under the new line
Also the new job quantity area is not responding anymore
index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Perhitungan Harga</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .select2-container {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .form-group {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    .table th {
      background-color: #f8f9fa;
    }
    .table td, .table th {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-4 mb-4">Form Perhitungan Harga</h1>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Jenis Pekerjaan</th>
            <th>Pekerjaan</th>
            <th>Kuantitas</th>
            <th>Satuan</th>
            <th>Harga Satuan</th>
            <th>Total Harga</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php include 'generate_form.php'; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Hitung Total Harga" class="btn btn-success">
      </div>
    </form>
    
    <?php include 'process_form.php'; ?>
  </div>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

generate-form.php
<?php
// Koneksi ke database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "konstruksi";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Cek koneksi
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Koneksi gagal: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Array untuk menyimpan jenis pekerjaan
$jenis_pekerjaan = array(
  "pekerjaan_persiapan",
  "pekerjaan_fondasi",
  "pekerjaan_struktural",
  "pekerjaan_dinding",
  "pekerjaan_atap",
  "pekerjaan_instalasi_listrik",
  "pekerjaan_plafond",
  "pekerjaan_accesories_kelistirkan",
  "pekerjaan_instalasi_pemipaan",
  "pekerjaan_penutup_keramik",
  "pekerjaan_accesories_pipa",
  "pekerjaan_pintu_jendela",
  "pekerjaan_pengecatan",
  "pekerjaan_pembesian",
  "pekerjaan_lainnya"
);

foreach ($jenis_pekerjaan as $jenis) {
  // Query untuk mengambil data pekerjaan dari tabel
  $sql = "SELECT kode, nama_pekerjaan, satuan, harga_satuan FROM $jenis";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='6' class='bg-light font-weight-bold'>".ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $jenis))."</td></tr>";
    
    // Menampilkan dropdown pekerjaan dan input kuantitas
    echo "<tr class='pekerjaan-row'>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<select name='pekerjaan[$jenis][]' class='pekerjaan-select form-control' data-placeholder='Pilih Pekerjaan'>";
    echo "<option value=''></option>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option value='".$row["kode"]."' data-harga='".$row["harga_satuan"]."' data-satuan='".$row["satuan"]."'>".$row["nama_pekerjaan"]."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='number' name='kuantitas[$jenis][]' min='0' class='kuantitas form-control'></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='satuan'></span></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='harga-satuan'></span></td>";
    echo "<td><span class='total-harga'></span></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
    // Menampilkan tombol "Tambahkan Pekerjaan"
    echo "<tr class='tambah-pekerjaan-row'><td colspan='6'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary tambah-pekerjaan' data-jenis='$jenis'>Tambahkan Pekerjaan</button></td></tr>";
  }
}

$conn->close();
?>

process-form.php
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  echo "<h2>Rincian Pekerjaan:</h2>";
  echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
  echo "<thead><tr><th>Jenis Pekerjaan</th><th>Pekerjaan</th><th>Kuantitas</th><th>Satuan</th><th>Harga Satuan</th><th>Total Harga</th></tr></thead>";
  echo "<tbody>";
  
  $totalHarga = 0;
  
  // Koneksi ke database
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "konstruksi";
  
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  
  // Cek koneksi
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Koneksi gagal: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  
  foreach ($jenis_pekerjaan as $jenis) {
    if (isset($_POST["pekerjaan"][$jenis]) && isset($_POST["kuantitas"][$jenis])) {
      $pekerjaan = $_POST["pekerjaan"][$jenis];
      $kuantitas = $_POST["kuantitas"][$jenis];
      
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($pekerjaan); $i++) {
        $kode = $pekerjaan[$i];
        $qty = $kuantitas[$i];
        
        // Query untuk mengambil data pekerjaan berdasarkan kode pekerjaan dari tabel yang sesuai
        $sql = "SELECT nama_pekerjaan, satuan, harga_satuan FROM $jenis WHERE kode = '$kode'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
          $namaPekerjaan = $row["nama_pekerjaan"];
          $satuan = $row["satuan"];
          $hargaSatuan = $row["harga_satuan"];
          $totalHargaPekerjaan = $hargaSatuan * $qty;
          
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $jenis)) . "</td>";
          echo "<td>$namaPekerjaan</td>";
          echo "<td>$qty</td>";
          echo "<td>$satuan</td>";
          echo "<td>Rp " . number_format($hargaSatuan, 0, ',', '.') . "</td>";
          echo "<td>Rp " . number_format($totalHargaPekerjaan, 0, ',', '.') . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          
          $totalHarga += $totalHargaPekerjaan;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  echo "</tbody>";
  echo "</table>";
  
  echo "<h3>Total Harga: Rp " . number_format($totalHarga, 0, ',', '.') . "</h3>";
  
  $conn->close();
}
?>



script.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initSelect2();
  
  $('.pekerjaan-select').on('change', function() {
    updateHargaTotal($(this).closest('.pekerjaan-row'));
  });
  
  $('.kuantitas').on('input', function() {
    updateHargaTotal($(this).closest('.pekerjaan-row'));
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.tambah-pekerjaan', function() {
    var jenis = $(this).data('jenis');
    var row = $(this).closest('.tambah-pekerjaan-row').prev('.pekerjaan-row').clone();
    row.find('select').val('').trigger('change');
    row.find('input[type="number"]').val('');
    row.find('.harga-satuan').text('');
    row.find('.satuan').text('');
    row.find('.total-harga').text('');
    $(this).closest('.tambah-pekerjaan-row').before(row);
    initSelect2();
  });
  
  function updateHargaTotal(row) {
    var selectedOption = row.find('.pekerjaan-select option:selected');
    var hargaSatuan = selectedOption.data('harga');
    var satuan = selectedOption.data('satuan');
    var kuantitas = row.find('.kuantitas').val();
    var hargaElement = row.find('.harga-satuan');
    var totalElement = row.find('.total-harga');
    var satuanElement = row.find('.satuan');
    
    hargaElement.text(hargaSatuan ? 'Rp ' + formatNumber(hargaSatuan) : '');
    satuanElement.text(satuan ? satuan : '');
    totalElement.text(hargaSatuan && kuantitas ? 'Rp ' + formatNumber(hargaSatuan * kuantitas) : '');
  }
  
  function initSelect2() {
    $('.pekerjaan-select').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).data('select2')) {
        $(this).select2({
          placeholder: 'Pilih Pekerjaan',
          width: '100%'
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  function formatNumber(number) {
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
  }
});

I tried to redo all the coding, but still I can't find the cause

Can you please try and boil this down a bit more, to what is actually essential to the problem? Is this a client, or a server side issue? By the looks of it, I am guessing the former, and that the actual processing of the data after submission, isn't really part of the issue. In that case, please remove those irrelevant parts, they just bloat the question.
